# How build a software with mutliple Linux utilities in a single executable file?

Tags: c, linux, bash, gcc, compilation

I'm currently working on a new projet, a single binary which have to contain lot of Unix utilities like Busybox.
For example i would like to be able to use netcat (with static dependencies) with my toolbox like that :
`./mytoolbox netcat`
But I don't know how to perform it.

Which architecture for this app will be the best ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Study and improve the source code of [sash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand-alone_shell), or download and improve the source code of [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) or of [zsh](https://zsh.org/)

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: Is your project open source? If yes, where is the source code?

Comment: I have a toolbox with hammers, saws, wrenches, knifes, screwdrivers etc. Now I'm gonna get a HUGE keyring to connect all the tools into one very bulky swizz army knife.

Comment: How is this question "opinion-based"? It's not asking if this is a good idea, it's asking the perfectly answerable technical question of how to accomplish it.

Comment: I need of this beacause, often I have to be on a lot of machines, and i don't want to install each package all the time on each machine, in addition sometimes i don't have internet connection. So I would like to have just a binary to use multiple tools.

Comment: Are these utilities that you wrote, or off-the-shelf utilities?  If I wanted to carry a bunch of my own tools around (the ones that tend to live under `~/bin` and `~/lib`), I might consider just building a tarball.  If it were off-the-shelf stuff, I might consider creating my own collection of package files (e.g. .deb files for Debian), and carrying those around, and installing them using `dpkg -i` if I wasn't on the net.  I get the impression that there are lots of modern tools for package management, but I don't know so I can't recommend any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish this:

1. Require the tools to be present on the system. This is by far the easiest option from the developer perspective, but has some drawbacks. It is less secure (what version are you calling?) and you'll need to handle the various differences between command versions.
2. Stop thinking you need one binary file. No serious application even considers this, because once it reaches any decent size, the link time just isn't worth it. Just ship the utilities you want alongside your applications and call those directly.
3. Embed the applications into your startup script/binary. An example of embedding data into a "script" is the NVIDIA driver installer. You use it like a shell script (it is a shell script) but has all the data appended to it, which the script then loads and uses. You can also embed the binary files into your executable directly, and then mmap them as executable code and, well, execute them. Not sure if you can `exec` a region of memory, otherwise you'll need to hook into the application code and do some voodoo black magic to initialise and load all libraries required (maybe you can use dyld.so for that).
4. Incorporate the source code of the utilities into your program, and call into their underlying procedures yourself (this means handling whatever their `main` does by yourself).

Personally I would go for option 2, and if you must, option 4.

Remember to respect all the software licenses in any of these cases.

Comment: Thank you for your response ! Yes the second one seem to be the easiest and the best solution. The fourth one seem to be cool, but need more development and more skills.

Answer (score 0):

A possible way is to have symbolic links to your executable. So build first your `mytoolbox` [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) file (in [elf(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html) format) and add symlinks (see [ln(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ln.1.html), [symlink(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/symlink.2.html), [symlink(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/symlink.7.html), [inode(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inode.7.html), [credentials(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html)...) like `ln -s mytoolbox mytoolchain`. Then the file `mytoolchain` is a [symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) to the executable `mytoolbox`.

Then, start your `main` function as:

```
int main(int argc, char**argv) {
  if (!strcmp(argv[0], "mytoolbox"))
      run_prog_my_toolbox(argc, argv);
  else if (!strcmp(argv[0], "mytoolchain"))
      run_prog_my_toolchain(argc, argv);
```

Another possibility is to load plugins using [dlopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) and [dlsym(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html).

Your `mytoolbox` executable has probably dependencies. See [execve(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), [ldd(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html), [readelf(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/readelf.1.html)

Look, as an example, inside the source code of [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), which behaves differently when started as `bash` or as `rbash` (it then [becomes a restricted shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Restricted-Shell.html)).

Consider using interpreters like [GNU guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/), [Lua](https://lua.org/),  or  or code generating libraries such as [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/).

Read also [*Linux From Scratch*](https://linuxfromscratch.org/)

Be aware of [software licensing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_license) issues. If you redistribute your executable, LGPLv3 could be relevant (for `libc.so.6`)

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I don't understand, in this case what represent mytoolchain ? What contain mytoolbox in this case ?